# TVP does not conform to table type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, table-valued-parameters

Below is the function that inserts my data.

```
                using (SqlCommand insSwipeDataCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    insSwipeDataCommand.Transaction = transaction;
                    insSwipeDataCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    insSwipeDataCommand.CommandText = "dbo.insSwipeData_sp";

                    SqlParameter attendeeTableParam = insSwipeDataCommand.Parameters.Add("@AttendeeTable", SqlDbType.Structured);
                    attendeeTableParam.Value = this.dataTable;
                    attendeeTableParam.TypeName = "AttendeeTableType";

                    // add orgid parameter
                    insSwipeDataCommand.Parameters.Add("@orgId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = this.organizationId;
                    insSwipeDataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

**insSwipeData_sp**

```
create PROC dbo.insSwipeData_sp
(@AttendeeTable         AttendeeTableType READONLY
,@orgId                 UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON


    DECLARE @enteredUserId  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    SET @enteredUserId = 'xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'

    -- Delete old Swipe records
    DELETE FROM dbo.swipeData_tbl
    WHERE orgId = @orgId

    -- CREATE Swipe Records
    INSERT INTO dbo.swipeData_tbl
    (orgId, sdid, rawData, enteredUserId, enteredUtc, manualEntry)
    SELECT @orgId, attendeeId, barcode
          ,@enteredUserId, GETUTCDATE(), 0 -- Consider ( datepart , date ) if date here is needed as NVARCHAR
    FROM @AttendeeTable
    WHERE barcode IS NOT NULL and LTRIM(RTRIM(barcode)) <> '';
END
```

Here is an image of my `AttendeeTableType` schema.
[image]

and here is an image of my `this.datatable` that i am using for my `attendeeTableParam`
[image]
On the `insSwipeDataCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` line i get the following error.

*The data for table-valued parameter "@AttendeeTable" doesn't conform to the table type of the parameter.*

Comment: Where/How is `this.dataTable` created?

Comment: Simple `private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable()`

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I meant how do you define the columns, and add data to it?

Comment: "SQL" is the standard that most RDBMS implement. "SQL Server" is Microsoft's enterprise RDBMS.

Comment: Just FYI: 1) you don't need to specify `TypeName` when using `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and 2) you don't need both LTRIM and RTRIM together since one of them alone will do the trick if the string is just spaces.

Answer (score 11):

Per the error, your data does not conform to the table type exactly. Note "exactly" -- if you do not specify types for the columns, they will be inferred, and they can easily be inferred incorrectly. The best approach here is to create a table that you know matches the table type definition:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("firstName", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 100;
dt.Columns.Add("lastName", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 100;
dt.Columns.Add("studentId", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 10;
dt.Columns.Add("email", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 100;
dt.Columns.Add("barcode", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 100;
dt.Columns.Add("dob", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 200;
dt.Columns.Add("major", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 200;
dt.Columns.Add("gender", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 200;
dt.Columns.Add("classCode", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 15;
dt.Columns.Add("currentclassCode", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 15;
dt.Columns.Add("entranceCode", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 15;
dt.Columns.Add("attendeeId", typeof(Guid));
```

And then use `.Clone()` to create a new table with the correct schema when you need to insert data. This way, if you have a type or length mismatch, it will be caught on the client end.

There is another approach you can take that does not rely on embedding the table definition into the application, which is fetching it from the database. There are pros and cons to this -- it requires an extra roundtrip to the database and it's not as easy to spot mistakes in the application logic if the types or columns don't match, but it does give you additional flexibility to change the type without having to change the application (adding a new, nullable column, for example).

```
var dt = new DataTable();
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(...)) {
    connection.Open();
    using (var command = new SqlCommand()) {
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "DECLARE @t dbo.AttendeeTableType; SELECT * FROM @t;"
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously you probably want to cache the results of this and `.Clone()`, rather than doing it for every command involving the table type parameter.

Comment: Oh, I spent a whole day trying to solve this, casting, converting and you solved it, I was just missing the setting MaxLength for the string column. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I reached this page while searching for similar issue that I was experiencing, but none of the replies did help me. After some head beating I found that the error is being generated in case when the data table being passed from the code has some data that does not match the TVP type specification.

For example if you defined the following type:

```
CREATE TYPE EmployeeType AS TABLE 
(
    EmpID BigInt, EmpName VARCHAR(100)
)
```

and suppose the data table that you are passing has (say) one `EmpName` that has more than 100 characters then "*** does not conform to table type" error is generated.

This solved my issue. Hope it will help others as well.

Comment: Is there any way by which we can turn off this warning for TVP and truncate the data like we can do it by SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF for a table?

Answer (score 2):

Even though Jeroen Mostert answer helped me solve one piece of the puzzle, this error was still popping up.

Here is what I learned;

> ###### Datatable created and passed as table value param should
> correspond to the sequence / order of field in table value type defined
> in sql.

So if your table type looks like below :

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[tvp_mytabletype] AS TABLE(
    [ID] BIGINT,
    [AddressCode] BIGINT,
    [Address] NVARCHAR(200) NOT NULL    
)
```

then define your DT with columns in exact same order/sequence like below :

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

//DataTable definition
dataTable.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(long));
dataTable.Columns.Add("AddressCode", typeof(long));
dataTable.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string)).MaxLength = 200;
```

Comment: This is the key: **Datatable created and passed as table value param should correspond to the sequence / order of field in table value type defined in sql.** thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your `attendeeId` is looks strange. It must be `Guid` in C# side.